# How to systematically take still renders of an object with random materials, camera location, lighting location/energy, and background using Python?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I'm trying to write a Python script in Blender that will:

- import one .dat file at a time from a folder of them
- create a camera and a point light a random distance away between -3 and 3 in all directions
- randomize the .dat objects' material, randomize the point lights energy level somewhere between very dim and very bright, point the camera at the .dat object
- take 10 still renders of the same .dat object, but randomizing everything after each render.

Once it has taken 10 still renders of the .dat object, with each render having the randomized properties stated above, I would like the script to delete the .dat object and then repeat the process with the next .dat file in the specified folder.

I had written a script from snippets I had found online, but there were a few things that didn't work. I also need to be able to specify an import preset to use while importing the .dat files. I'm using Blender 3.4, Windows 10, and an add-on titled "Import LDraw".
I would also like the resolution of the renders to be 640 x 640. If anyone could either write a script that can do what I outlined, or give me some pointers as to why my code doesn't work, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks for reading!

````py
    # import dependencies
import bpy
import os
import random

# define variables

# set render resolution
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 640
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 640

input_path = r"D:\Administrative Folder\Administrative Folders\%CommonDocumentsFolder%\LDraw\parts"
output_path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\BlenderImages\\"

num_stills = 10

# Set the preset to use when importing the object
preset_name = "Script"

camera_name = "MyCamera"

# List of materials
materials = bpy.data.materials

# set up the scene

# Deselect all objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Select all objects in the scene
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.select_set(True)

# delete selected objects
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Create the initial camera
bpy.ops.object.camera_add()

# Set the name of the camera
bpy.context.object.name = camera_name

# Get the camera object by name
camera_obj = bpy.data.objects.get("MyCamera")

# Create the initial point light

# create light datablock
light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="my-light-data", type='POINT')

# create new object, pass the light data 
light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="my-light", object_data=light_data)

# link object to collection in context
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)

# change light location
light_object.location = (0, 0, 5)

# create a plane
# bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=150)
# bpy.context.object.name = "Ground"

# loop over every .dat file in the specified input folder
for filename in os.listdir(input_path):
    if filename.endswith(".dat"):
        
        # Import the .dat file that is currently being iterated over
        # Define the file path of the .dat file
        file_path = os.path.join(input_path, filename)
        bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_path, use_custom_props=True, imported_object_collections=preset_name)
        Current_Lego = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        Current_Lego.name = "Lego"
        obj = bpy.data.objects.get("Lego")
        
        for i in range(num_stills):
            
            # Place the camera titled "MyCamera" in a random position between ranges -3 and 3
            camera_obj.location = (round(random.uniform(-3.00, 3.00), 2), round(random.uniform(-3.00, 3.00), 2), round(random.uniform(-3.00, 3.00), 2))
            
            # Point the camera at the newly import object
            # Set the camera rotation
            camera_obj.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
            camera_obj.rotation_euler = obj.location - camera_obj.location
            
            # Randomize the location of the light
            light_object.location = (round(random.uniform(-3.00, 3.00), 2), round(random.uniform(-3.00, 3.00), 2), round(random.uniform(-3.00, 3.00), 2))
            
            # Randomize the brightness of the light
            light_object.data.energy = random.randint(50, 150)
            
            # Apply a random material to the Lego object
            mat_slot = obj.material_slots[0]
            mat_slot.material = materials[random.randint(0, len(materials) - 1)]
            
            # Set the world background to a random color
            bpy.context.scene.world.use_nodes = True
            nodes = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes
            color_node = nodes.get("Background")
            if color_node is None:
                color_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBackground')
                color_node.name = "Background"
            color_node.inputs[0].default_value = [random.random() for i in range(3)] + [1.0]
            
            # take a still for a specified number of times, changing the camera angle, lighting, material, and background before each still is rendered
            # set output path and render image
            output_file = output_path + filename + i + ".png"
            bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_file
            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

        # after the the specified number of stills for a .dat file has been rendered, delete the imported object from the scene
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)
        
# after every .dat file has had its specified number of still rendered, print 'Done'
print("Done")
```
````